# Android Storage Access Framework: Open document read/write

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

My task: Using the new API (target OS level is 21 / Lollipop), let the user pick one or more files, so that the app can modify them.

I am following the official example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

But no matter what I try, the returned URIs are all read-only.
Whenever I try to open them for writing, I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Media is read-only`:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Media is read-only
     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:148)
     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:618)
     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:986)
     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:733)
     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:709)
     at com.udojava.android.test.Test.modifyFile(Tools.java:95)
```

I tried:

```
OutputStream os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
```

and

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw");
```

Though the documentation states, that it it is not needed anymore, I even put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to my manifest, it didn't help.

My code so far:

```
private static final int ACTION_PICK_FILE = 99;
private List<Uri> selectedFiles = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // (...)

    findViewById(R.id.pick_file_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_PICK_FILE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == ACTION_PICK_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        selectedFiles = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        ClipData data = resultData.getClipData();
        if (data != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.getItemCount(); i++) {
                selectedFiles.add(data.getItemAt(i).getUri());
            }
        }
        if (resultData.getData() != null) {
            selectedFiles.add(resultData.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What providers are you picking from, as a user? There's no strict requirement that all providers grant write access. Also, if you could, please post your entire stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: Picking from the gallery / camera images, I added the exception to the question.

Comment: Hi Dear , i am facing same issue. Did you got any issue? please help